# Django - zappa issue

Tags: python, django, zappa

```
{'message': 'An uncaught exception happened while servicing this request. You can investigate this with the `zappa tail` command.', 'traceback': ['Traceback (most recent call last):\\n', '  File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 572, in handler\\n    with Response.from_app(self.wsgi_app, environ) as response:\\n', '  File \"/var/task/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py\", line 287, in from_app\\n    return cls(*_run_wsgi_app(app, environ, buffered))\\n', '  File \"/var/task/werkzeug/test.py\", line 1119, in run_wsgi_app\\n    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)\\n', \"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable\\n\"]}
```

I got this error on Django Admin when I deployed Django after updating DB model.

I tried to redeploy the project from scratch. sometimes it works but this issue occurs every hour.